# Android database table creation

Tags: android, database

I am trying to create two tables in a database in my android application, one table is created but the second is not being created. Here is the following code

```
package com.example.visiting_card;

import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String Databasename="contact.db";
private static int version=1;
private String KEY_ID="id";
private String Table_name="contact_details10";
private static String KEY_NAME="name";
private static String Email="email";
private static String Contact="contact";
private static String Company="company";
private static String address1="address1";
private static String address2="address2";
private static String State="state";
private static String Table_userpass="userpass";
private static String User="user";
private static String Pass="pass";

public DataBaseHandler(Context context)
         {
    super(context,Databasename, null, version);
    Log.d("jhgd","sd");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

/*  String Table_create="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ Table_name + "(" + KEY_ID + "  
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " text," + Email + " text,"
            + Contact +" text," + Company + " text," + address1 + " text," + address2 +  
" text," + State +" text" + ")";
        db.execSQL(Table_create);
        Log.d("msd",Table_create);
        Log.d("datbase", "datebase created");*/
}
public void table(SQLiteDatabase db){
String Table_create="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ Table_name + "(" + KEY_ID + " 
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " text," + Email + " text,"
        + Contact +" text," + Company + " text," + address1 + " text," + address2 + " 
text," + State +" text" + ")";
    db.execSQL(Table_create);
    String table_User = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_userpass + " (" + User + " TEXT PRIMARY 
KEY,"+Pass+ " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(table_User);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF  EXITS " + Table_name);
    Log.d("datbase", "datebase deleted");
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addcontacts(Contact contact,User_Password user_pass){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    table(db);
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    ContentValues values1=new ContentValues();
    Log.d("name",contact.Name);
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.Name);
    values.put(Email, contact.Email);
    values.put(Contact, contact.Contact);
    values.put(Company,contact.Company);
    values.put(address1,contact.address1);
    values.put(address2, contact.addreaa2);
    values.put(State, contact.State);
    values1.put(User,user_pass.getuser());
    values1.put(Pass, user_pass.getpassword());

    db.insert(Table_name, null, values);
    db.insert(Table_userpass, null, values1);
    Log.d("sds", "inserting");
}
public ArrayList<Contact> getallcontact(){
    ArrayList<Contact> contactlist=new ArrayList<Contact>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table_name;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            Contact contact=new Contact(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7));

  Log.d("msg",cursor.getString(0)+cursor.getString(1)+cursor.getString(2)+cursor.getString(3));
            contactlist.add(contact);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactlist;



  }


}
```

hIn this error is no table found Table_useerpass but firest table is creted .
I am using table function to crete the table

Comment: Try clearing app data from your device's settings and run again.

Comment: Is there an error log? Where is `addcontacts(...)` being called from? Also, trying sticking with the Java naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare it as a variables out side the

```
private static final String Table_create="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ Table_name + "(" + KEY_ID + " 
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " text," + Email + " text,"
        + Contact +" text," + Company + " text," + address1 + " text," + address2 + " 
text," + State +" text" + ")";

private static final String table_User = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + Table_userpass + " (" + User + " TEXT PRIMARY 
KEY,"+ Pass + " TEXT" + ")";
```

and try to call those things in

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(Table_create);
        db.execSQL(table_User );

    }
```